# Одновременное употребление первого и второго лица, наст. и буд. времени у Маяковского

Tags: грамотная-речь, ссп

> Проживешь свое пока,
>   много всяких грязных ракушек
>   налипает нам на бока.

([Маяковский](http://v-mayakovsky.com/lenin.html))

Проживешь **ты**, а ракушки налипают **нам** на бока.

Почему бы не написать в первом лице: *проживем*?

Дополнение

Еще один вопрос возник — как объяснить странное сочетание будущего и настоящего времени: *пока проживешь, налипает*? Естественно было бы так: *пока  проживешь, налипнет* или *пока живешь, налипает*.

Answer (score 2):

Видо-временная соотнесённость, конечно, важное условие синтаксической нормы, но ведь есть ещё и грамматическая синонимия, и стилистическое использование грамматических категорий. Маяковский использует мастерски и экспрессивную лексику, и экспрессивный синтаксис, и экспрессивную морфологию.

Проживешь свое пока,

много всяких грязных ракушек

налипает нам на бока.

Глаголы будущего времени обычно получают заряд экспрессии при переносном употреблении в иных временных планах. Будущее совершенного вида может указывать на действия, обращенные к настоящему времени: *Словечка в простоте не **скажет** - все с ужимкой (Гр.).* **Скажет - будущее время в значении настоящего. Проживёшь - будущее вр. в значении настоящего,** вернее, совершенный вид в значении несовершенного (проживёшь - проживаешь). Союз **пока** указывает на протяжённость действия во времени, на его незавершённость. Это же явно разговорные конструкции, Маяковский ввёл в поэзию язык улиц, язык площадей. "Поживёшь с моё, проживёшь своё"  намного экспрессивнее, чем проживаешь или проживаем. Точно так же, как "налипнет" не передаст значения **длительного процесса налипания**, только результат.

Синонимия форм глагола 2 лица ед.ч. и 1 лица множ. числа тоже используется для экспрессии - для придания обобщённости субъекта действия. Проживёшь **ты как один из нас**, и ракушки налипают **всем нам** на бока. Логика не нарушена, а вот степень обобщения вышла на первый план, ведь Маяковскому важно показать это самое **"мы"**, в которое вливается **"я"**. Личностное переживание сливается с общественным.

Так что здесь всё продумано, это создание особой экспрессии с помощью **стилистического использования грамматической синонимии.**

Comment: Это очень интересное объяснение. Помнимаю и принимаю. Маяковский - бунтарь и новатор, глаголом жжет. Но зайдем с другой стороны. Прошла бы такая фраза на школьных экзаменах, будь она написана учеником?

Comment: Зависит от многих факторов, прежде всего от опыта и эрудиции проверяющего. Лучше, конечно, соблюдать классические нормы, но если ученик умело использует грамматическую синонимию, это даже приветствуется, а если неумело - посчитают за ошибку. К тому же здесь художественный стиль речи, а ученик  на экзамене создаёт текст в публицистическом стиле, где разговорные конструкции нежелательны. Лучше не умничать и писать по правилам.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, можно это так оправдать: первая строка не персонифицирована, она в том же смысле, что "*живёшь себе, живёшь и вдруг видишь...*" - далее может быть произвольный текст о наблюдениях, которые как бы предлагается представить себе, встав на место говорящего ("*что к тебе, к нему - да ко всем нам - поналипло всякой грязи*").

Comment: Мне кажется, это какая-то лингвистическая эквилибристика, и только для того, чтобы найти оправдание.

Comment: Конечно, в некотором роде эквилибристика. Маяковский был таким неординарным человеком, что ему хочется найти оправдание. Но мне кажется, Alex_ander предложил вполне разумный подход. Я бы свои ощущения от строчек Маяковского сформулировал примерно так же.

Answer (score 1):

***Проживешь своё пока*** – односоставное **обобщенно-личное** предложение, применяется для выражения **общих суждений, применимых к любому лицу**, например: *Выше головы не прыгнешь. Любишь кататься – люби и саночки возить.*

Comment: И каков вывод? Мы ведь не говорим: "Любишь кататься – **любим** и саночки возить." Можно ло свободно менять лицо?

Comment: А что странного в том, что два предложения (в составе СПП) имеют разную форму сказуемого? Каждый человек проживает свою собственную жизнь, а не вместе с кем-то (обобщение в односоставном предложении), далее следует двусоставное предложение: нам, каждому из нас. Маяковский очень грамотно использовал здесь возможности обобщенной формы. Ничего неординарного я здесь не вижу.

Comment: А мне кажется странным. Если говорить Вашим язком (обобщенно-личное предложение применяется для выражения общих суждений), то "проживешь своё пока" -  это не суждение, а лишь первая часть его, почему же две части "общего суждения" содержат глаголы в разном лице и числе, как они согласуются между собой? Так же, как и "Любишь кататься – **любим** и саночки возить"?

Comment: Откуда "любим"? Там - "люби", обращение ко 2-му лицу. .

Comment: Конечно, вам хотелось бы увидеть такой приглаженный текст: "Проживем свое пока, много всяких грязных ракушек налипает нам на бока". Можете считать это авторским приемом художественной выразительности:  ярко,  пусть необычно, но обоснованно, привлекает внимание, вызывает вопросы, в отличие от стандартного "серенького" синтаксиса.

Comment: (1) Уже прогресс! Мы оба согласны, что это необычно. Далее вопрос об обоснованности. Чем обосновано?

Comment: Дальше стоп прогресс. Семантическое обоснование формы 2-го лица  уже указано в ответе и первом комментарии, больше мне нечего добавить. У формы "проживем" нет значения грамматического обобщения, это определенно-личное, а не обобщенно-личное предложение. Маяковский не изучал эту грамматику, но тонко чувствовал язык. В оправданиях он не нуждается, всё четко и ясно.